# Are there other occurrences of a scene before the opening credits?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the last episode (S06E07), we had this scene before the opening theme.

Did this happen before? I don't really remember.

And is there any special reason that they do this uncommon thing on the show?

Comment: Do viewers even need the opening credits anymore? I think by now we all know we're watching Game of Thrones. We could squeeze another two minutes of drama into the episodes if they dumped the opening credits sequence.

Comment: Opening credits is a must in tv shows. It's the show's identity, and GoT opening is not static. The map changes as the story rolls. I don't think they should ever remove it, even to add a few more seconds of scenes, they need the intro.

Comment: "Opening credits is a must in tv shows." There are shows where they're barely more than a title card and a few music notes. "Lost" was basically one tone and the word "Lost" fading in.

Comment: I didn't mean they all must have a 3 minute long opening, but they must have something that shows the TV show name.

Comment: I like the opening of Game of Thrones, and would be sad if it was removed. That said, didn't the pilot also have a [cold open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_open)... in more that one way? :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes this has been done before.**

Here are other examples of Game of Thrones cold opens.

- Season One Episode One began with a scene North of the Wall introducing the White Walkers and the Nights Watch.
- Season Three Episode One began with Samwell Tarly fleeing the Wights and White Walkers.
- Season Four Episode One began by showing Ned Stark's greatsword Ice being forged into Oathkeeper and Widow's Wail by Tywin Lannister.
- Season Five Episode One began with Cersei Lannister meeting Maggie the Frog in the first ever flashback to occur on the show.
- Season Six Episode Seven begins with the reappearance of the Hound.

  As for why this was done, the producer, Bryan Cogman says this to [Entertainment Weekly](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/06/05/game-thrones-the-hound-interview):

  > **EW**: The episode also started with a cold open, which is obviously very unusual, particularly for midseason. What prompted that?
  >
  > **Bryan Cogman**: We figured **it would make [The Hound's] reveal more impactful** if the audience hadn’t seen [ McCann's] name in the opening credits first.
- Season Seven Episode One began with

  > Arya poisoning the remaining Frey family.

Comment: I didn't think about the actor's name in the credits. That was a smart move. I just find it odd that in the previous times that we had "cold openings" they all happened in first episodes of the seasons. All seasons except 2 had one episode with the before credits scene.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I know for a fact seasons 2 and 6 didn't begin with a cold open. I can't find any other mid season cold opens, but I could be missing one.

Comment: "impactful" Ouch. Well, he's a producer, not a writer. *(Looks him up on Wikipedia.)* Ouch, he's a writer too.

Comment: They didn't show actor's name before the appearance of Hound, but they showed Kit Harrington in titles before the resurrection :D

Comment: @Schullz the thing with Kit Harington is that we knew we'd see the actor. The question was whether or not he'd be playing a dead body. If Rory's name was shown it wouldn't be expected and could spoil the episode.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Is there a reason you haven't accepted this answer? Let me know if theres something that needs to be added or changed in this answer in order for it to be correct.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot! :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Merriam Webster: [Impactful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impactful)

Comment: @Jolenealaska: Lots of words in the dictionary that shouldn't see the light of day. ;-)

Comment: @Schullz I wonder if there was an upper limit to how many episodes Kit Harrington would be willing to continue playing a dead body? Would he have played an entire season as dead Jon Snow if he were still paid? Perhaps like in the film *El Cid* Jon Snow's dead body could have inspired his army.

Comment: Season Five Episode One, when young Cersei meets Maggy the Frog, wasn't a cold open.

Comment: @user87442 I'll need to re-watch it.  I did find another reference to it being a cold open in an article posted today. https://theringer.com/game-of-thrones-daenerys-prophecy-melisandre-the-prince-that-was-promised-acb29b53ec0d

Comment: Do you guys think we'll have a cold open on the last season as well? Make your guesses guys, that's the last chance XD